# How can I reload the Live Preview Iframe window using JS

Tags: javascript, live-preview

I tried to reload the iframe window using JS but haven't had any luck getting the lp-iframe iframe element, I was thinking I could do it using the Window.Craft object but not sure how?

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  var iframe = document.querySelector('.lp-iframe');
  iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
Craft.livePreview.updateIframe(true);
```

to update the Live Preview iFrame

Comment: It tells me that Craft is not defined? I tried Window.Craft and Craft and also putting this in a setTimeout

Comment: You can only use that in your CP. There is actually no way that Craft is not defined, otherwise your entire CP would not work. Of course you have to include your file after all Craft assets. Please make sure to implement your code after the `livePreview` is initialized. Are you using Craft 3 or Craft 2?

Comment: Hey I'm using Craft 3, if I console.log the live preview iframe I see there isn't a Craft object but that's only within the CP context. Is there a way to trigger a refresh from within the page that is being previewed?

Comment: Never mind I got it working using `window.parent.Craft.livePreview.updateIframe(true);`